# JavaFx: varriable value become null when passing from JavaFX thread to new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, listview, javafx

in my chat software i want to update ListView but when i call a method i get null pointer exception like below

```
   public class RoomController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */

    public static ObservableList<String>  members = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML public static Button send;
    @FXML static  ListView names;
    @FXML static HTMLEditor outmsg;
    @FXML static HTMLEditor showBox;
    @FXML static ContextMenu listMenu;

    static void updateRemove(String newuser) {
        try
        {
        showBox.setHtmlText(showBox.getHtmlText()+newuser+"<br>  has left room");
        System.out.println(newuser+"has left room");
        members.remove(newuser);
        System.out.println("helloji update remove");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    @FXML public void listMenuAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        MenuItem item = (MenuItem)event.getSource();

        LoginController.getInstance().c.sendPrivateRequest((String)names.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

    }
    @FXML public void sendAction(ActionEvent event)
    {


     LoginController.instance.c.sendMessage(outmsg.getHtmlText());


    }
    public  static void updateList(String name)
    {
        try
        {
        showBox.setHtmlText(showBox.getHtmlText()+"<br> new user entered in room");
        System.out.println("new user enterd"+Client.message.getNewuser());
        System.out.println("beginning update list");
        members.add(name);
        System.out.println(members);
        System.out.println("add user request fullfilled");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
     public  static void initList(Vector<String> name)
    {
        try
        {
        System.out.println("list initializing");

            members.setAll(name);

          System.out.println(members);
        System.out.println("list initialized");

        System.out.println("public room created");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public static void showMessage(String msg)
    {

        try
        {
       showBox.setHtmlText(showBox.getHtmlText()+""+msg);
            System.out.println("showing msg   "+msg);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO


        try
        {

         names.setItems(members);
         showBox.setHtmlText(showBox.getHtmlText()+"<br> welcome "+Client.username);
             System.out.println("welcome  "+Client.username);




         System.out.println(names.getItems());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }    
}
```

in above code initList() ,updateRemove(), listUpdate() method show parameters value null while i am passing the values!!

please help me!!!

here below is the code from where i am calling the above methods

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {

        try
        {
             if(in==null)
                 {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("inputstream created:::::::::::::::::thread");

                }
             message = new Message();
            message = (Message)in.readObject();
            if(message.getMode().equals("addUser"))
            {
                System.out.println("add user request"+message.getNewuser());
               Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        RoomController.updateList(message.getNewuser());
                    }
                });


            }
           else if(message.getMode().equals("getmsg"))
            {
               // message.setMessage(message.getMessage());
                 Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       RoomController.showMessage(message.getMessage());
                    }
                });


            }
           else if(message.getMode().equals("addallUser"))
            {
                System.out.println("join room response");
                for(String names1 : message.getOlUsers())
                {
                    System.out.println("add all users "+names1);
                }
                   Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      RoomController.initList(message.getOlUsers());
                    }
                });


            }
           else if(message.getMode().equals("leaveUser"))
            {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    RoomController.updateRemove(message.getNewuser());
                    }
                });


            }
           else if(message.getMode().equals("privateChatRequest"))
           {
               System.out.println("private request rediraction get from"+message.getNewuser());

               Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       CreateRoom.createPrivateroom("privateWindow.fxml", message.getNewuser());
                   }
               });

           }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

and below is the error that i get

list initializing
[]
list initialized
public room created
add user requestsandeep
new user enterdnull
beginning update list
[null]
add user request fullfilled

Comment: Can you put a `break;` to the end of try block, so that the while loop is looped only 1 cycle. Then see if the data is still `null`.

Comment: yeeee!!!  finally i have solved this problem by studying long tutorial of oracle about concurrency and worker thread .